# Injecting spring bean to an abstract class

Tags: spring, abstract-class, autowired

I'm trying to inject (autowire) a spring bean to an abstract class but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    protected SecurityProvider securityService;

    public BaseEntity() {
    }
}
```

And the injected class:

```
@Component
public class SecurityService extends SecurityProviderImpl implements SecurityProvider {

    @Autowired
    public SecurityService(ICipherDescriptor cipherDescriptor) {
    super(cipherDescriptor);
    }
}
```

The SecurityService gets initialized just fine (I can see it while debugging) but the class that inherit from BaseEntity cannot use the injected SecurityService since it is null (doesn't get injected for some reason).

I tried doing it via XML as well, defining the BaseEntity as abstract:

```
<bean id="baseEntity" abstract="true" class="com.bs.dal.domain.BaseEntity">
    <property name="securityService" ref="securityService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="securityService" class="com.bs.dal.secure.SecurityService">
    <constructor-arg ref="cipherDescriptor" />
</bean>
```

but still with no success.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you add the first couple of lines from the derived class as well?

Comment: How are you getting an instance of BaseEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's wrong here. I'm trying to inject a spring bean to an entity - which is impossible (unless you use aspectJ weaving) since the entities are not instantiated/managed by Spring. Make sense, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If your `BaseEntity` is also instantiated by spring, you just need to add a `parent` attribute to the bean definition to link it to your `BaseEntity` definition like so:

```
<bean id="baseEntity" abstract="true" class="com.bs.dal.domain.BaseEntity">
   <property name="securityService" ref="securityService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="derivedEntity" parent="baseEntity" class="com.bs.dal.domain.DerivedEntity"/>

<bean id="securityService" class="com.bs.dal.secure.SecurityService">
   <constructor-arg ref="cipherDescriptor" />
</bean>
```

In short, the two key parts to such a definition are the **abstract** attribute on the parent class and the **parent** attribute on the subclass.